# Execute a function for each list, in a list of lists faster than a for loop [web scraping]

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I am building a scraping script.
I have a .csv file with customers' detail - one customer per row, the first cell in each row is the customer name. I want to scrape Google News and take the first 5 results for each of those customer names.

Right now I have a for loop, so it iterates each line, take the customer's name, run the scraping function and print the results.
The downside is that is quite slow, as it has to complete one line before moving to the next one.

I was wondering whether exists something faster and I thought of reading the rows from the csv file and have a list of lists; then run the scraping function in parallel for all the lists.

```
import bs4,requests
import csv


class Scraper():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ScrapeWebStr(self,account):

        base_url = 'https://news.google.com/search?q={}%20when%3A3d&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'
        request = requests.get(base_url.format(account)) 
        webcontent = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.content,'lxml') 
        counter = 0 
        global articles_str
        articles_str = ""
        for i in webcontent.findAll('div',{'jslog':'93789'}):  #All the news in GN have jslog 93789. This iterate in all the news 
            if counter ==5:
                break
            else:
                for link in i.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/articles/")},limit=1): #takes the article link for each news
                    if any(keyword in i.select_one('h3').getText() for keyword in keyword_list): #filter articles that have a keyword
                        articles_str = articles_str + str(i.select_one('h3').getText()) + '\n' + "https://news.google.com"+str(link.get('href')) + '\n' + ('-' * 80) + '\n' 
                        counter +=1
                        if counter == 5: 
                            break                       

    def fileOpen(self,file):
        data = open(file,encoding='utf-8')
        csv_rows = list(csv.reader(data))
        return csv_rows


#FILTERS
keyword_list = ['ACQUISITION', 'Acquisition', 'BALANCE', 'BAN', 'BOND', 'BRAND', 'Balance', 'Ban', 'Bond', 'Brand', 'CAPITAL', 'COSTS', 'CRISIS', 'CUSTOMERS', 'Capital', 'Costs', 'Crisis', 'Customers', 'DEBT', 'DEMAND', 'Debt', 'Demand', 'ECONOMY', 'Economy', 'FINANCE', 'FINANCIAL', 'FUND', 'Finance', 'Financial', 'Fund', 'GROWTH', 'Growth', 'INVESTOR', 'IPO', 'IPO', 'Investor', 'LAYOFF', 'Layoff', 'MARKET', 'MERGER', 'Market', 'Merger', 'NEW', 'New', 'PAY', 'PAYABLES', 'PROFIT', 'Pay', 'Payables', 'Profit', 'RATING', 'RECEIVABLES', 'REVENUES', 'Rating', 'Receivables', 'Revenues', 'SALES', 'SHARE', 'SHEET', 'SIZE', 'STOCK', 'SUE', 'Sales', 'Share', 'Sheet', 'Size', 'Stock', 'Sue', 'TREND', 'Trend', 'USAGE', 'Usage', 'acquisition', 'balance', 'ban', 'bond', 'brand', 'capital', 'costs', 'crisis', 'customers', 'debt', 'demand', 'economy', 'finance', 'financial', 'fund', 'growth', 'investor', 'ipo', 'layoff', 'market', 'merger', 'new', 'pay', 'payables', 'profit', 'rating', 'receivables', 'revenues', 'sales', 'share', 'sheet', 'size', 'stock', 'sue', 'trend', 'usage'] #List of keywords to filter

#UPDATE + MAIL VERSION
Execution = Scraper()
metadata = Execution.fileOpen("Excel for Scraping.csv")
for row in metadata:
    Execution.ScrapeWebStr(row[0])
    print(articles_str)
```

The for loop slows everything down and I have unused computing power to spare. I feel that the solution may include multiprocessing, but I don't understand how to take the item [0] for each list in the main list and run the multiprocessing without a for loop.
I don't want you to write the code for me but any hint would be a great help!

Thanks a lot

Comment: One way to get concurrency without resorting to multiprocessing would be to use `subprocess` in Python. You'd write a script that makes a single query, then write a separate script that launches the first. Use `subprocess` in the "launcher" script to run the "single query" script against each target without waiting for completion.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/) and [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) to make requests concurrently, `fake_useragent` to fake user agents, and also simplified CSS selectors in code. A fully working example is [here on Repl.it](https://repl.it/@serpapi/google-news-async-python).

Please note, that I've commented `Execution.fileOpen` and used a list of search terms instead.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv, time, asyncio, httpx

from fake_useragent import UserAgent


class Scraper():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def ScrapeWebStr(self, account: str) -> str:
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            ua = UserAgent()

            headers = {"User-Agent": ua.random}

            params = {
                "q": f"{account} when",
                "hl": "en-US",
                "gl": "US",
                "ceid": "US:en"
            }

            response = await client.get(
                'https://news.google.com/search',
                params=params,
                headers=headers)

            webcontent = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
            counter = 0

            articles_str = ""

            # All the news in GN have jslog 93789. This iterate in all the news
            for i in webcontent.select('div[jslog="93789"]'):
                if counter == 5:
                    break
                else:
                    for link in i.select('h3 a[href*="/articles/"]'):
                        article_text = link.getText()

                        # filter articles that have a keyword
                        if any(keyword in article_text
                               for keyword in KEYWORD_LIST):
                            articles_str += f"""{article_text}
    https://news.google.com{link.get('href')}
    {'-' * 80}
    """

                            counter += 1

                            if counter == 5:
                                break

            return articles_str

    def fileOpen(self, file):
        with open(file, encoding='utf-8') as data:
            list(csv.reader(data))


# List of keywords to filter
KEYWORD_LIST = [
    'ACQUISITION', 'Acquisition', 'BALANCE', 'BAN', 'BOND', 'BRAND', 'Balance',
    'Ban', 'Bond', 'Brand', 'CAPITAL', 'COSTS', 'CRISIS', 'CUSTOMERS',
    'Capital', 'Costs', 'Crisis', 'Customers', 'DEBT', 'DEMAND', 'Debt',
    'Demand', 'ECONOMY', 'Economy', 'FINANCE', 'FINANCIAL', 'FUND', 'Finance',
    'Financial', 'Fund', 'GROWTH', 'Growth', 'INVESTOR', 'IPO', 'IPO',
    'Investor', 'LAYOFF', 'Layoff', 'MARKET', 'MERGER', 'Market', 'Merger',
    'NEW', 'New', 'PAY', 'PAYABLES', 'PROFIT', 'Pay', 'Payables', 'Profit',
    'RATING', 'RECEIVABLES', 'REVENUES', 'Rating', 'Receivables', 'Revenues',
    'SALES', 'SHARE', 'SHEET', 'SIZE', 'STOCK', 'SUE', 'Sales', 'Share',
    'Sheet', 'Size', 'Stock', 'Sue', 'TREND', 'Trend', 'USAGE', 'Usage',
    'acquisition', 'balance', 'ban', 'bond', 'brand', 'capital', 'costs',
    'crisis', 'customers', 'debt', 'demand', 'economy', 'finance', 'financial',
    'fund', 'growth', 'investor', 'ipo', 'layoff', 'market', 'merger', 'new',
    'pay', 'payables', 'profit', 'rating', 'receivables', 'revenues', 'sales',
    'share', 'sheet', 'size', 'stock', 'sue', 'trend', 'usage'
]


async def main():
    start_time = time.monotonic()
    print(f"Started main")

    async def scrape_and_print(row):
        start_time = time.monotonic()
        print(f"Searching for '{row}'")

        # Execution.ScrapeWebStr(row[0])
        articles_str = await Execution.ScrapeWebStr(row)

        print(
            f"Finished searching for '{row}' in {time.monotonic() - start_time}"
        )

        print(articles_str)

    # UPDATE + MAIL VERSION
    Execution = Scraper()
    # metadata = Execution.fileOpen("Excel for Scraping.csv")
    metadata = ['stackoverflow', 'google']

    await asyncio.gather(
        *[scrape_and_print(row) for row in metadata], return_exceptions=True)

    print(f"Finished main in {time.monotonic() - start_time}")


asyncio.run(main())
```

**Output**

Trailing dot is fine in `news.google.com.`. FQDNs have dots at the end (source: [1](https://serverfault.com/a/803037/206829), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name#Syntax), [3](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/73937/19723)).

```
Started main
Searching for 'stackoverflow'
Searching for 'google'
Finished searching for 'stackoverflow' in 5.42717178100429
Stack Overflow reports strong growth from COVID-19 workplace changes
    https://news.google.com./articles/CBMiY2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnpkbmV0LmNvbS9hcnRpY2xlL3N0YWNrLW92ZXJmbG93LXJlcG9ydHMtc3Ryb25nLWdyb3d0aC1mcm9tLWNvdmlkLTE5LXdvcmtwbGFjZS1jaGFuZ2VzL9IBbmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnpkbmV0LmNvbS9nb29nbGUtYW1wL2FydGljbGUvc3RhY2stb3ZlcmZsb3ctcmVwb3J0cy1zdHJvbmctZ3Jvd3RoLWZyb20tY292aWQtMTktd29ya3BsYWNlLWNoYW5nZXMv?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Stack Overflow gets $85M Series E funding to expand SaaS product
    https://news.google.com./articles/CBMiZWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnRlY2hyZXB1YmxpYy5jb20vYXJ0aWNsZS9zdGFjay1vdmVyZmxvdy1nZXRzLTg1bS1zZXJpZXMtZS1mdW5kaW5nLXRvLWV4cGFuZC1zYWFzLXByb2R1Y3Qv0gFwaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGVjaHJlcHVibGljLmNvbS9nb29nbGUtYW1wL2FydGljbGUvc3RhY2stb3ZlcmZsb3ctZ2V0cy04NW0tc2VyaWVzLWUtZnVuZGluZy10by1leHBhbmQtc2Fhcy1wcm9kdWN0Lw?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Stack Overflow expands its Teams service with new integrations
    https://news.google.com./articles/CAIiELYwgKfey9CR8SXDOjhn0zMqFAgEKg0IACoGCAowlIEBMLEXMOc_?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MongoDB: A Database For The New Era
    https://news.google.com./articles/CAIiEC1Lr6ctqyb6pi2PkH_xsfAqFggEKg0IACoGCAowkqEGMJBZMLLouwY?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    EXCLUSIVE: Communities, brand and then product — CEO explains how Stack Overflow flipped the script on softwar
    https://news.google.com.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?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
Finished searching for 'google' in 2.2639846410020255
Google Home: 5 ways to fix the issue when Google Assistant doesn't understand you
    https://news.google.com./articles/CAIiEEH9NNUgXleahne_qOb-cRcqFQgEKgwIACoFCAow4GowoAgwhuCMBg?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Pocket Casts is up for sale nearly three years after acquisition by public radio consortium
    https://news.google.com./articles/CAIiEE0kkabL7el7Et9iUgNvaFoqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowyoD5CjD5z-ACMM_rvwU?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Google reportedly requires new Android TV devices support AV1 video decoding
    https://news.google.com./articles/CBMiUWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnhkYS1kZXZlbG9wZXJzLmNvbS9nb29nbGUtcmVxdWlyZXMtbmV3LWFuZHJvaWQtdHYtYXYxLXZpZGVvLWRlY29kaW5nL9IBVWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnhkYS1kZXZlbG9wZXJzLmNvbS9nb29nbGUtcmVxdWlyZXMtbmV3LWFuZHJvaWQtdHYtYXYxLXZpZGVvLWRlY29kaW5nL2FtcC8?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Google previewing new Nest Hub alarms with more customization, tones, and ‘Sunrise’
    https://news.google.com./articles/CAIiEPFJ-0ZIW0D3KmRfgtg-QLkqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowyoD5CjD5z-ACMM_rvwU?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Google 'throwing its weight around' by burying links to some commercial news sites, experts say
    https://news.google.com./articles/CAIiEMds5Hwsm-sBaVKmnmg4yZ8qFggEKg4IACoGCAow3vI9MPeaCDDciw4?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
Finished main in 6.28738788398914
```

Alternatively, you can use [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/news-results) to access extracted data from Google News. It has a free trial.

**Disclaimer**: I work at SerpApi.